# how to handle async actions correctly?

Tags: redux

I have a async action

```
function fetch(url) {
  dispatch => {
    request(url).then(
      resp => dispatch({type: FETCH_SUCCESS, resp}),
      error => dispatch({type: FETCH_FALUIRE, error})
  );
```

}
}

UI has a page to list all items, when click one of them, it dispatchs a action with url of that item.

when I click item1 first, then I click item2 quickly, if the response of item2 returns earlier than item1. the data of item2 in store will be overwritten by item1.

```
fetch('http://remote/items/item1'); //first
fetch('http://remote/items/item2'); // then
```

How can I ignore the result of the item1? or how can I make dispatch of item always trigger after item1

what I can think of is, dispatch the url before send request.

```
function fetch(url) {
  dispatch => {
    dispatch({type: FETCH_START, url});
    request(url).then(
      resp => dispatch({type: FETCH_SUCCESS, resp, url}),
      error => dispatch({type: FETCH_FALUIRE, error, url})
    );
  }
}
```

in the reducer, I check the url to decide if I should ignore the response.

```
function reduceFetch(state = initialState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case FETCH_START:
      return {initialState, action.url};
    case FETCH_SUCCESS:
      if (state.uri === action.url) {
        return {state, resp: action.resp};
      } else {
        return state;
      }
    ...
  }
```

}

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution should work. Atleast if you ignore something crazy like

1. Request item1
2. Request item2
3. Request item1 again.
4. Third request is comming back.
5. First request failed. Or first request is comming back and item1 was changed in between the requests.

Alternatively you could make your `fetch` function to dispatch events only on the latest call.

```
const fetchLatest = (called => url => {
  const snapshot = ++called

  return dispatch => request(url).then(
    resp => snapshot === called && dispatch(...),
    error => snapshot === called && dispatch(...)
  )
})(0)
```

Comment: Thanks Tarabanko, This is what I thought, but didn't know how to implementation.